# Getting started with basic transportation problems like Wolf, Cabbage, Goat with either C# or F#

Tags: f#, river-crossing-puzzle

OK. this might be a very basic question to please don't flame me but I have been googling I want to learn how to write solutions to transportation problems like Wolf, Cabbage, and Goat or traveling salesman using F#

so far my research has taken me to these resources on the web

http://mat.gsia.cmu.edu/orclass/integer/integer.html

http://www.zib.de/Publications/Reports/SC-95-27.pdf

[Fox-Goat-Cabbage Transportation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8138775/fox-goat-cabbage-transportation)

http://www.qauprogrammers.com/Article/File-192324030/PROLOG-Programming-with-NET

but despite reading thru these, I have not been able to "think" on how should such a problem be solved in F# type of language

Comment: So what is your question exactly? Your title talks about C# or F#, but you seem to be concerned about integer / combinatorial optimization types of problems.

Comment: You need to expand a bit more on what you have done. Your references are good, but all that you have quoted for your work is a handful of problems. For example, have you solved the language in an imperative language before? Do you have a sample? Have you tried the typical basic conversion methods? (loops -> recursion, minimizing stateful objects etc.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommend going thru the excellent article [Escape from Zurg: An Exercise in Logic Programming.](http://web.engr.oregonstate.edu/~erwig/papers/Zurg_JFP04.pdf) Although the functional language of choice there is Haskell, it should give you enough ideas about programming of optimal search problems functionally.

Also [Escape from Zurg in Scala](http://blog.jonhnnyweslley.net/2008/08/escape-from-zurg.html) has full source code easily portable to F#.